# How can we verify the direction of electric displacement is radial?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I have two questions about electric displacement $D$.

The following is a problem in Griffiths.

> > A long straight wire, carrying uniform line charge $\lambda$, is surrounded by rubber insulation out to a radius $a$. Find the electric displacement.
> >
> > (solution in the text) Drawing a cylindrical Gaussian surface, of radius $s$ and length $L$, applying Gauss theorem, we find
> >     $$D(2\pi s L) = \lambda L$$
> >     $$D = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi s}\hat{s}$$

1. I think for using the symmetry, we, in advance, verify that the direction of $D$ is radial. How can we verify it?

Griffiths also wrote the following advice.

> > When you are asked to compute the electric displacement, first look for symmetry. If the problem exhibits spherical, cylindrical, or plane symmetry, then you can get $D$ directly from the Gauss theorem like the above problem. (Evidently in such cases $\nabla \times P$ is automatically zero, but since symmetry alone dictates the answer you're not really obliged to worry about the curl.)

2. How can we get $\nabla \times P=0$ when there is symmetry? Also does $\nabla \times P = 0$ implies that direction $D$ is radial? I want to know how to prove.

Comment: What is $P$ here? Polarization?

Comment: Sure. It is polarization

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $$\mathbf D = D_\rho \hat{\mathbf \rho}+ D_\varphi \hat{\mathbf \varphi} +D_z \hat{\mathbf z}.  $$Then because of the cylindrical symmetry $\frac{\partial}{\partial \varphi}=0$, $D_\varphi $ should not be a function of $\varphi$. When we take a circle of raidus $\rho_0$ which is parallel to the xy plane and have a point of intersection with the z axis, the line integral of $\mathbf D$ along the circle should be zero under an assumption that relative permittivity is constant over all domain.
   $$ \oint_C \mathbf D \cdot d\mathbf l = \oint_C \mathbf D \cdot \hat{\mathbf \varphi} \rho d\phi =2\pi\rho_0 D_\varphi = 0 $$
   So we get $D_\varphi =0$. Using similar way, we also obtain $D_z=0$.
2. $\mathbf P$ is propotional to $\mathbf E$ as long as the medium is isotropic and linear. Therefore $\nabla\times \mathbf P =0$ is trivial in electrostatics.

Comment: I got the (1), but there isn't any mention that the medium is isotropic or linear. I don't know how to prove it by symmetry. (Actually, the concept of linear dielectric is introduced in the next section of this problem.)